# Compiling arrays stored in external text files (C++ compiled using command line g++)

Tags: c++, arrays, include, g++, external

I am a novice c++ programmer so please forgive me if this is a naive question. I have files containing large arrays holding tens-of-thousands of strings that I have used previously in javascript applications. Is there some way to include these into C++ source code so that the arrays are compiled along with the code?

At present, the files are formatted as functions that return (javascript) literal arrays, like this:

```
// javascript array stored in .js text file
function returnMyArray()
{
return ["string1", "string2", "string3", ... "stringBigNumber"];
} // eof returnMyArray()
```

I 'include' the external file with the usual javascript script & src tags and assign the array with something like:

```
myArray = returnMyArray();
```

I want to achieve the equivalent in c++, i.e. assign an array stored in a file to an array in my c++ source code so that the data is available for execution when compiled.

I suppose in theory I could copy and paste (suitable formatted) arrays from files into my c++ source code but they are too large for this to be practical.

I can easily re-write the files to whatever format would be easiest to have c++ access the data - either in c++ array syntax or one string per line to be read into an array.

In a similar vein, is there an easy way to include files containing custom function libraries when compiling with g++ in terminal? (my web searches show plenty of ways for various IDE applications but I am writing source in vim and compiling with g++ on the command line).

I am sorry if this is trivial and I have missed it but I am stumped!

Thank you.

Comment: You could twiddle the format so they're written as valid C++ array definitions, then #include them.  But there's no way to get it to work leaving them as native javascript without writing some sort of parser or terrible preprocessor hack.

Comment: @Wug thanks. I'm feeling a little dumb but it was you specifically mentioning #include that solved this... I'd learnt about headers etc. but it hadn't clicked that I can also #include native code from a file. I've just experimented and can load an array stored in a .cpp file with #include, even as a local array within a function. Exactly what I needed! Simples!

Comment: I'll add an answer with exactly how I'd do it just in case you're curious.

Comment: @Wug I was about to ask - how do I vote you without an answer! Yes please, an answer would be great.

Comment: Theoretically (because I haven't checked and I'm not sure) you can use Qt - QML to read the array from JavaScript and then use it as usual array in C++. But it's a lot of work to do so, simple reformatting and including is easier I guess.

Comment: Just wondering, but aren't the array values intermixed with the rest of the js source? If you just `#include` this into C++ source that's invalid syntax.

Comment: @greatwolf - yes the javascript syntax had to go but I simply edited by .js files to strip out everything before and including the opening [ and everything after the closing ] to leave a comma-separated list of quoted strings, renamed it .cpp and used:   'code' string myArray [] = {  #include "arrayList.cpp"   } ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd structure this:

file: **data.array**

```
/* C++ style comments are ok in this file and will be ignored
 * both single and multiline comments will work */

// the data in the array is a comma seperated list, lines can be any length
    1, 2, 3, 4,
    5, 6, 7, 8,
    9, 10, 11, 12,
    // more comma seperated data
    9996, 9997, 9998, 9999
```

file: **class.h**

```
extern int myArray[]; // you should fill in the size if you can
// more stuff here
```

file: **class.cpp**

```
// if you have an editor that highlights syntax and errors, it may not like this
// however, #include is handled before compiling and performs a blind substitution
// so this is perfectly legal and should compile.
// Visual C++ 2010 highlights this as an error, but the project builds fine.

int myArray[]
{
    #include "data.array"
};

// other definitions of stuff in class.h
```

Comment: Thanks. What does the class.h file do? In my experiments I wrote the array in one file and simply used #include to reference it where needed in the source code - it worked fine but can it cause problems without the class.h? And, is the class.h included as a header outside all functions?

Comment: If you wanted to use the array in other files, you would have to declare it in this way.